# Incorporating paypal into my PHP shopping cart?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm building a simple shopping cart using PHP and I want to be able to use paypal with it. I want to use the tools described here: 
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside

This seems to be the easiest way to go about doing this. I looked over at their development page, and was really confused, but this made sense. My only problem is with this I have been told that it's fairly easy to change the prices. Now I could run a script to check the return from paypal to check to see if their order price matches their cart total, but I want to stop this before it happens. The one thing I did take from the development site was their token call. Would I be able to build a function that creates the buy now button by providing all the items through the method above, and then making a token call to link the id of those items and prices to the button? I'm just a bit confused, a lot of people have said to look at the documentation, but I'm having a difficult time understanding all of it so any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just pass the variable that has the total to paypal

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$TOTAL">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with [Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview) you can u se the [cart upload method](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload) to send all of the info over to the PayPal checkout.

If you're comfortable with PHP, though, I'd recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).  This will free you up to a lot more with your checkout experience.

You might want to check out this [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It makes this very simple for you.  With that library it's just a matter of knowing which API calls to make and then using the included files to pass in your own data accordingly.

For Express Checkout you would be using [SetExpressCheckout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getexpresscheckoutdetails-api-operation-nvp), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doexpresscheckoutpayment-api-operation-nvp).